# MySQL SUM by if statement

Tags: mysql, sql

I have 3 columns in my MySQL table **type**, **sum** and **custom_sum**  where custom_sum can be empty, and i am stuck on modifying query

```
SELECT `type`, SUM(`sum`) FROM `localhost-test` GROUP BY `type`
```

What i need is to use **sum** in `SUM()` if **custom_sum** is empty, and use **custom_sum** if it is not.
Is it possible to sum by different columns based on "if" statement in mysql ?

Comment: `SUM(ISNULL(custom_sum, \`sum\`))`

Comment: What exactly you mean by saying "empty"? If it's NULL value, then use COALESCE as @Notolysses told below in his answer. If empty means 0 or "", then you need to use IF or CASE. Just don't do as user3414693 said, but enclose IF or CASE inside SUM(...).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If `custom_sum` value is `null` :

```
SELECT 
    `u.type`,
    SUM(COALESCE(`custom_sum`,`sum`))
FROM 
    `localhost-test` 
GROUP BY 
    `type`
```

If `custom_sum` value is `empty` (`==''`) :

```
 SELECT 
    `u.type`,
    SUM(CASE WHEN `custom_sum` = '' THEN `sum` ELSE `custom_sum` END)
FROM 
    `localhost-test` 
GROUP BY 
    `type`
```

Comment: can use coalesce for empty string like NULL??

Comment: @Ronald Alexander Kailola : Thank you for a tip, I've updated my answer in case value is empty but not null.